# Copy PostgreSQL data to the same table, replacing some fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with three columns:

```
id, 
name:string, 
location:int
```

I need to copy all records with `location = 14` to the same table, but I need the copies to change locations to `15`. Of course, id's must be changed too, to their autoincrement values.

How do I do that in PostgreSQL?

Comment: u want to update location 14 to 15 ??u can use update query

Comment: @GaneshP No he can't just update because he needs new ids

Comment: No, I need to _copy_ them, leaving original records intact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into t (name, location)
select name, 15
from t
where location = 14
```

Comment: I don't need to delete it, I need to copy them, leaving original records intact.